# Getting multiple data from several tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

I try to get data from two connected tables.

```
$query="SELECT a.*, (SELECT `city_id` FROM `staff-city`) as cities FROM `staff`  as a WHERE a.id=2";
```

i get the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row'
```

It's logic, cause i have three cities for this id.
The main goal is to get a row with id(2) from staff and join all data (city names) from staff-city - do it with one query and i need a final result such this:

```
array (
[id]=>value,
[..]=>values,
[cities]=>array(
    [0]=>2,
    [1]=>26
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT a.*, b.city_id FROM staff a , staff-city b WHERE a.id=2"
```

Comment: nope.. i have multiple data in staff-city, your way i get only first row